# How to use multiprocessing Pool when evaluating many images using scikit-learn pipeline?

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, multiprocessing, bigdata

I used a GridSearchCV pipeline for training several different image classifiers in scikit-learn. In the pipeline I used two stages, `scaler` and `classifier`. The training run successfully, and this is what turned out to be the best hyper-parameter setting:

```
Pipeline(steps=[('scaler', MinMaxScaler()),
                ('classifier',
                 ExtraTreesClassifier(criterion='log_loss', max_depth=30,
                                      min_samples_leaf=5, min_samples_split=7,
                                      n_estimators=50, random_state=42))],
         verbose=True)
```

Now I want to use this trained pipeline to test it on a lot of images. Therefore, I'm reading my test images from disk (150x150px) and store them in a hdf5 file, where each image is represented as a row vector (150*150=22500px), and all images are stacked upon each other in an `np.array`:

```
X_test.shape -> (n_imgs,22500)
```

Then I'm predicting the labels `y_preds` with

```
y_preds = model.predict(X_test)
```

So far, so good, as long as I'm only predicting some images.

But when `n_imgs` is growing (e.g. 1 Mio images), it doesn't fit into memory anymore. So I was googling around and found some solutions, that unfortunately didn't work.

I'm currently trying to use `multiprocessing.pool.Pool`. Now my problem: I want to call multiprocessing's `Pool.map()`, like so:

```
n_cores = 10
with Pool(n_cores) as pool:
    results = pool.map(model.predict, X_test, chunksize=22500)
```

but suddenly all workers say:

[image: All workers say 'Stopping']

without further details, no matter what chunksize I use.

So I tried to reshape `X_test` so that each image is represented blockwise next to each other:

```
X_reshaped = np.reshape(X_test,(n_imgs,150,150))
```

now `chunksize` picks out whole images, but as my model has been trained on 1x22500 arrays, not quadratic ones, I get the error:

```
ValueError: X_test has 150 features, but MinMaxScaler is expecting 22500 features as input.
```

I'd need to reshape the images back to 1x22500 before `predict` runs on the chunks. But I'd need a function with several inputs, which `pool.map()` doesn't allow (it only takes 1 argument for the given function).

So I followed Jason Brownlee's post: [Multiprocessing Pool map() Multiple Arguments](https://superfastpython.com/multiprocessing-pool-map-multiple-arguments/#Change_The_Target_Function_to_Unpack_Arguments)

and packed several variables into a tuple, which I then unpacked in a wrapper function, before calling `model.predict()`:

```
n_imgs = X_test.shape[0]

X_reshaped = np.reshape(X_test,(n_imgs,150,150)) # reshape each row to 150x150px images

input_tuple = (model,X_reshaped) # pack model and data into a tuple as input for the wrapper

with Pool(n_cores) as pool:
    results = pool.map(predict_wrapper, input_tuple, chunksize=22500)
```

and the wrapper function:

```
def predict_wrapper(input_tuple):

    model, X = input_tuple # unpack the input tuple

    n_imgs = X.shape[0]
    X_mod = np.reshape(X,(n_imgs,150*150)) # reshape back

    y_preds = model.predict(X_mod)

    return y_preds
```

But: `input_tuple` doesn't get unpacked correctly in the wrapper function:

[image: Wrong unpacking result]

As you can see: instead of assigning `model` to `model` and `X_test` to `X`, it splits my pipeline and assigns the `scaler` to `model` and the `classifier` to `X`.

So, long story short:

does anybody have a solution how I can use my trained scikit-learn pipeline and do prediction on a plethora of images? I'm not bound to use `multiprocessing.pool.Pool`, but I didn't find any other solution so far...

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, now I finally got this working! Thanks to [Frank Yellin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6457407/frank-yellin)'s [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75115034/3806733) I realized that my problem seemed to be the `chunksize` I explicitly passed. I thought that by doing so I could force `pool.map()` to take a certain number of images per chunk, but it behaved differently and complained about the wrong dimensions of the given chunks.

But inspired by Frank's answer I rather defined the chunks before the call to `pool.map()` and then passed the chunks to it. Now the images are passed chunkwise to the single workers.

Seems I could not see the forest for the trees...

So in the end it looks like this:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

import h5py
import joblib
import numpy as np


def main_prediction_batch():

    # --- load model ---
    model_URL = "<path to model.pkl>"
    with open(model_URL, 'rb') as model_file:
        model = joblib.load(model_file)

    # --- load image and label file ---
    hdf5_file_URL = "<path to hdf5 file with images and labels.hdf5>"
    with h5py.File(hdf5_file_URL, mode='r') as hdf5_file:
        X_test = hdf5_file["Images"][:] # ️ (n_imgs, 150*150)
        y_test = hdf5_file["Labels"].asstr()[:] # ️ (n_imgs,)

    n_imgs = X_test.shape[0]

    n_cores = 10

    image_batching = 10000  # or whatever you want your batch size to be
                            # doesn't have to be a multiple of n_cores!
    chunk_ranges = [(i, min(i + image_batching, n_imgs)) 
                    for i in range(0, n_imgs, image_batching)]

    # define chunks of several images
    chunks = [
        (X_test[chunk_ranges[i][0]:chunk_ranges[i][1], :])
        for i in range(len(chunk_ranges))
        ]

    with Pool(n_cores) as pool:
        results = pool.map(model.predict, chunks)

    # stack the predictions to get a final row vector
    y_preds = np.hstack(results) # can now be compared with y_test

    return y_preds

# --------------------------
#           MAIN
# --------------------------
if __name__ == '__main__':
    
    y_preds = main_prediction_batch()
```

When I now look at it... it was complicated to describe but the final solution was quite simple... thanks a lot for enlightening me!

Answer (score 1):

When you call `pool.map()` on a numpy array, the array is broken up along its first dimension.

So if you called `pool.map(my_func, X_test)`, this will cause `my_func` to be called `n_imag` times, each with a 1-dimensional array of size 22500.

You have already mentioned that `X_test` is too big to fit into memory. It might make sense to have each subprocess read a range of images on its own from the database, process those, and send you back the results, rather than you sending the images to it.

```
def process_image_ranges(image_range):
    start, end = image_range
    # read images start [include] to end (exclusive) and process them
    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    image_count = 1_000_000 # or whatever the count is
    image_batching = 1024 # or whatever you want your batch size to be
    image_ranges = [(i, min(i + image_batching, image_count)) 
                    for i in range(0, image_count, image_batching)]
    with mp.Pool() as pool:
        result = pool.map(process_image_ranges, image_ranges)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I actually wanted to do this... but inside your function `process_image_ranges()` I need access to `X_test` (my numpy array of images). And no matter how I pass `X_test` to your function (using `pool.map()`, `.starmap()`, `partial()`), I always get this "Stopping" behaviour like in my question. All the workers say "Stopping" before even entering the function... 

Comment: I think that's your problem right there. You've already said that X_test is huge and doesn't fit in memory.  And now you're trying to make 10 copies of it.  Your processes are failing before they even start because they can't get the space you need.    You might want to look at numpy.memmap, where the array lives in a file and all your processes look at the same file.  But you *don't* want to be mapping over X_test.

Comment: Thanks for sticking with me here! Your words brought me to the right path - see my own answer.

Comment: Sorry.  I had purposely avoided chunksize in my code.  I should have stated that more explicitly.

Comment: No problem.  I read over it at first, but suddenly it caught my eye what you said...